# Image displays in design view, but doesn't show up in emulator or on the phone

Tags: android, image

Displaying image on android:

Image displays perfectly fine in a design view of `Eclipse`, but doesn't show up in emulator or on the phone. Here is the layout snippet:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/YYY"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textXXX"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="Trouble"
    android:ems="10"
    android:src="@drawable/xxx_yyy"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: have you got solution

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your situation should not happen. But if this is really happening then you can re-check with these lines :

1. Enable **Layout Boundaries** :
   If your device is `developer mode enabled` then **Settings -> Developer Options -> Show Layout Boundary**

   else go to **Settings -> About Phone -> click 5 times on baseband version** and your device will be `developer mode enabled` and execute above step

   Using this, your layout will display with its boundary lines on all edges. If your layout is being hidden on device or emulator with other large layouts then you can check this easily. If boundaries are not visible, your layout is not on `foreground` now, you need to check about other overlapping layouts
2. You can set `background` color of your layout and outside part of layout. i.e. your layout has `background` as **Green** (00FF00) and outside part has `background` as **Red** (FF0000). This also helps to identify where our layout is.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of image should be lower than `2048x2048 px` size.